# How to date as a user input in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am new to shell scripting..
I want a script  to get any date as a input from user and print date of 3 days back?

example:
If user enters date as 2013-01-01
then output should be

2012-12-29.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have GNU date, then this will work:

```
user_date=2013-01-01
date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$user_date - 3 days"
```

With BSD date, you'd have to do like this:

```
user_date=2013-01-01
date -j -v -3d +%Y-%m-%d -d "${user_date//-}0000"
```

because BSD date needs date to be in the format `YYYYmmddHHMM`.

I don't have a Solaris now to test there. If you're in Solaris then hopefully there is `gdate`, and you can use the first option, just replace the `date` command with `gdate`.

Whichever OS you are in, there are two important points:

1. In what format can you pass dates to the `date` command. I tested that GNU date can accept `YYYY-mm-dd` format (and probably many others), while BSD needs `YYYYmmddHHMM`.
2. In what format can you ask for a difference. With GNU date simply `DATE - 3 days` works, with BSD date it's trickier with `-j -v -3d` flags.

`man date` of your system should help you get through these hurdles. In the worst case, you could do all the `date` operations you need in `perl` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
date --date="3 days ago"
```

to get get date of 3 days back.

Comment: He needs to get -3 days relative to some other date coming from user input.

Comment: Oh ok, +1 to your answer then :)